# Convert a column to datetime by removing certain parts of characters

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, lubridate

I have a df like below and I am trying to convert the datettime column to a datetime format.

```
ID <- c("A","A","B","B")
datettime <- c("2015-12-03T13:04:06-06:00","2015-12-03T13:54:06-06:00","2015-12-03T16:04:06-06:00","2015-12-03T19:54:06-06:00")
df <- data.frame(ID,datettime)
```

the datettime column in my dataset is a character. I am trying to convert it to a datetime format but unable to get it right.

```
library(lubridate)
df$datettime <- ymd_hms(df$datettime)
#The problem here is the hours,minutes and seconds get messed up. 

df$datettime <- as.POSIXct(df$datettime,format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
#This just ouputs NA's in the column
```

My desired output is

```
  ID           datettime
1  A 2015-12-03 13:04:06
2  A 2015-12-03 13:54:06
3  B 2015-12-03 16:04:06
4  B 2015-12-03 19:54:06
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You almost got it: `df$datettime <- as.POSIXct(df$datettime,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`. BTW: what is this funny `-06:00` at the end of each string? Have never seen this format. But luckily the format string that I have given ignores this part anyhow.

Comment: That funny thing is because of the AM & PM that comes while I am parsing this column from JSON. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also try this:

```
df$datettime <- paste(substr(df$datettime,0,10),substr(df$datettime,12,19))
library(lubridate)
df$datettime <- ymd_hms(df$datettime)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to extract the string in two parts. `df$datettime <- substr(as.character(df$datettime), 1, 19)` is enough and lubridate seems to be able to cope with the `T` between date and time.

Comment: yeah i just noticed that after seeing other answers posted. I didn't think they would deal with the "T" and "-6:00" very well but I guess they do

Comment: I like this solution too with lubridate. Thanks road_to_quantdom and @Stibu

Comment: Actually, one does need to remove the `-06:00`. If it is left intact, lubridate adds 6 hours to the times.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add a dash and colon between the separators in your date. This will give you your desired output.

```
# original code from above:

ID <- c("A","A","B","B")
datettime <- c("2015-12-03T13:04:06-06:00","2015-12-03T13:54:06-06:00","2015-12-03T16:04:06-06:00","2015-12-03T19:54:06-06:00")
df <- data.frame(ID,datettime)

# convert to a POSIXct object
df$datettime <- as.POSIXct(df$datettime,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

df
  ID           datettime
1  A 2015-12-03 13:04:06
2  A 2015-12-03 13:54:06
3  B 2015-12-03 16:04:06
4  B 2015-12-03 19:54:06
```

Comment: This answer does not work. It should be `df$datettime <- as.POSIXct(df$datettime,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`. And your output does not agree with the output that the OP requested.

Comment: Actually. yes. he missed the T in that.

Comment: @Sharath this answer is incorrect... the times do not match up with your desired output

Comment: Your last approach with `as.POSIXct` and without the `T` separator gives `NA`s on my machine.

Comment: Have you actually run the first three lines of your code (i.e., the definition of the OP's dataframe) again before executing your last approach `df$datettime <- as.POSIXct(df$datettime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`? Otherwise, it wouldn't make much sense to run this line of code on data that is already properly formatted by your `lubridate` solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @cryo111. I didn't realize that lubridate was adding 6 hours to the times. I ended up removing the lubridate section altogether as POSIXct was able to deal with the timeshift problem.